# set the start point of CGRect iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, popup

I created a Popup like what in the following link 
[Popup](https://github.com/levey/LeveyPopListView)
and everything are Ok, but if I want to change the size of this popup I go to the file "LeveyPopListView.m" in function

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

and change the values in this line

```
CGRect bgRect = CGRectInset(rect, 50, 90);
```

but if I want to change the value of the start point of this popup, how can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time the system sends the `drawRect:` message, it is too late to change the position and size of the view.

You need to change the frame of `_tableView`.  It's set on lines 33-36 of `LeveyPopListView.m`.  You didn't say exactly how you want to change it, but you might be able to get the effect you want by changing the definition of `POPLISTVIEW_SCREENINSET` on line 12.

Comment: yes changing the value of POPLISTVIEW_SCREENINSET leads to change the start point, thanks so much